# SMS goes to the inbox when the mobile is disconnected

Tags: mobile, sms, java-me, wma

I'm using J2ME WMA to send/receive SMS into a specific port, which in my case is port 50000. When one of the mobile devices is not running the application the message goes to the inbox, which by default is port 0.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PushRegistry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/) resolves the issue but it's only available in WMA 2.0.

Check the [WMADemo sample](http://read.pudn.com/downloads142/sourcecode/mobile/j2me/617039/WMADemo/src/example/sms/SMSReceive.java__.htm) at JavaME SDK 3.0.