# Transfer SMS from a Java phone over GPRS (i.e. run an SMS gateway)?

Tags: java, sms, midp, s40

Is it possible to transfer SMS's from a Java based phone (either generic Java ME or Nokia Series 40) over GPRS - i.e. effectively to run an SMS gateway, without a PC?

I am aware that:

- this is not possible through just MIDP, since [MIDlets cannot access the SMS inbox directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793696/reading-sms-from-inbox-in-j2me).
- Gammu is a possibility, and in fact I currently use it.  However, this permits connection to a computer via Bluetooth or data cable, but not via an internet or GPRS interface (naturally, since AT commands presumably cannot be sent that way).  Hence, to get to a server on the Internet, you need a PC.
- SMS gateways exist for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.smsgatewayultimate) and [Blackberry](http://www.icecoldapps.com/blackberry/sms-server.html) but not for these "featurephones."

From my research it appears that this task is not possible.  However, I just want to check if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while I programmed midp devices, but have you seen Nokia SMS Api?
http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Documentation/Java_API_specifications.xhtml#sms

I think it should be possible to read SMS in midlet, but permissions apply, and depending on the phone and/or midlet signature the resulting application would ask each time the sms is to be read (as far as I remember). Therefore you wouldn't get automatic relay as Gammu.

**Edit**: Have you seen this:
[Receive text message using J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626475/receive-text-message-using-j2me)

Comment: Thanks, but that says "Nokia SMS API is supported only in Nokia 3410."  Presumably that means that any other model of Nokia would not run it?  I have a 6233, unfortunately, along with a range of second hand other Java phones (Samsung, Micromax etc.).

Comment: Ahh... yes indeed, but I could swear there was a way to read SMS from midlets at least on some devices, look for other JSRs... Still the permission problem apply.

Comment: The internet is full of comments that reading SMS from midlets is not possible, e.g. see [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/183644-Receive-inbox-sms-to-j2me-midlet-with-nokia-sms-api) or [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/144452-How-to-receive-a-SMS-on-port-0-using-a-MIDlet-before-letting-the-inbox).  Nokia's [Wireless Messaging API](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Wireless_Messaging_API). also says "You can.. not [receive] normal SMS from the inbox." I hope you're right but I can't find it :)

Comment: The linked questio n is listening on port 50001, isn't it?  I gathered that normal SMS messages arrive on port 0.